# infinite scroll fires before the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I am using the following line of code to fire the appending of extra item 100px before the user is at bottom:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
if ($(window).scrollTop() + height + 100 >= $(document).height())
```

The problem is that many times there are multiple append commands sent. If user is reaches 100px before the bottom the command is executed. The command is executed again and again as the user keeps scrolling up and down.

I have tried this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + height == $(document).height()) {
        // anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll events fire very frequently in most browsers. I would guess it's firing multiple times before the first request returns. You probably want to add a flag to prevent requests if there is already one in flight.

```
var requesting = false;

function renderPage() { /* ... */ }

function makeRequest() {
  if (!requesting) {
    // Go ahead and fetch the next page.
    requesting = true;
    $.ajax(...).then(renderPage).always(function() {
      requesting = false;
    });
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (/* scrolled to 100px above the bottom */) {
    makeRequest();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have a similar infinite scroll script running in my site. Try doing this:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Trigger Funtion when browser scroll triggered
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10){
//do action here
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```